# How to save a table from Datatables to a database in Django?

Tags: django, ajax, datatables

I'm using Datatables to display tables in Django on the server side. After searching for a phrase, I have a button ready to save the current table after filtering to Excel. I would like the second button to create a new table in the database and save the same table to it as for Excel.
I don't know how I can send AJAX data to Django and read it in views in such a way that I can query the database.

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      function newexportaction(e, dt, button, config) {
             var self = this;
             var oldStart = dt.settings()[0]._iDisplayStart;
             dt.one('preXhr', function (e, s, data) {
                 data.start = 0;
                 data.length = 2147483647;
                 dt.one('preDraw', function (e, settings) {
                     // Call the original action function
                     if (button[0].className.indexOf('buttons-excel') >= 0) {
                         $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.excelHtml5.available(dt, config) ?
                             $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.excelHtml5.action.call(self, e, dt, button, config) :
                             $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.excelFlash.action.call(self, e, dt, button, config);
                     }
                     dt.one('preXhr', function (e, s, data) {
                         settings._iDisplayStart = oldStart;
                         data.start = oldStart;
                     });
                 });
             });
             dt.ajax.reload();
         }
            $("#tb").DataTable({
                "lengthChange": true,
                "paging": true,
                "searching": true,
                "oLanguage": {
                  "sSearch": "Szukaj:",
                  },
                "language": {
                  "processing": "Przetwarzanie",
                  "lengthMenu": "Pokaż _MENU_ elementów",
                  "info": "Wyświetlono od _START_ do _END_ z _TOTAL_ elementów",
                  "zeroRecords":    "Nie znaleziono pasujących elementów",
                  "paginate": {
                      "first":      "Pierwsza",
                      "last":       "Ostatnia",
                      "next":       "Kolejna",
                      "previous":   "Poprzednia"
                  },
                  "emptyTable":     "Brak danych do wyświetlenia",
                },
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
               
                buttons: [
                    {
                        extend: 'excel',
                        titleAttr: 'Excel',
                        title: '',
                        action: newexportaction
                    },
                ],
                 dom: 'B<"clear">lfrtip',
    //          "destroy": true,
                "pageLength": 15,
                "ordering": false,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "paging2/",
                    "type": "get"
                },
            });
        });
```

views.py:

```
def paging2(request):
    draw = int (request.GET.get ('draw')) # record the number of operations
    start = int (request.GET.get ('start')) # start position
    length = int (request.GET.get ('length')) # length of each page
    search_key = request.GET.get ('search[value]') # search keyword
    order_column = request.GET.get ('order [0] [column]') # sort field index
    order_column = request.GET.get ('order [0] [dir]') #Ordering rule: ase / desc
 
         # sql query all data, then do paging, the speed is slow
    # if search_key:
    #     result = query(search_key)

    # else:
    #     result = select_all()
    # data = result[start:start+length]
    # count = len(result)
 
    # sql for paging, fast
    if search_key:
        sql_search = "SELECT NAZWA,TEL,NIP,Adres,WWW, EMAIL, Branza, NAZWA_SCRAPERA FROM gus_all t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM matka_new t2 WHERE t2.NIP = t1.NIP) AND LENGTH(TEL) = 9 AND `STATUS` = 'AKTYWNY' AND NAZWA_SCRAPERA is NOT NULL AND Branza like '%%%s%%'" % search_key
        sql_search_len = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gus_all t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM matka_new t2 WHERE t2.NIP = t1.NIP) AND LENGTH(TEL) = 9 AND `STATUS` = 'AKTYWNY' AND NAZWA_SCRAPERA is NOT NULL AND Branza like '%%%s%%'"% search_key
        result, count = query(sql_search, sql_search_len)
        data = result[start:start + length]
    else:
        sql = """
        SELECT NAZWA,TEL,NIP,Adres,WWW, EMAIL, Branza, NAZWA_SCRAPERA FROM gus_all t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM matka_new t2 WHERE t2.NIP = t1.NIP) AND LENGTH(TEL) = 9 AND `STATUS` = 'AKTYWNY' AND NAZWA_SCRAPERA is NOT NULL
        LIMIT %s OFFSET %s
        """
        data = select_by_page(length, start, sql)
        # data = select_by_page(start, start + length)
        sql_len = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gus_all t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM matka_new t2 WHERE t2.NIP = t1.NIP) AND LENGTH(TEL) = 9 AND `STATUS` = 'AKTYWNY' AND NAZWA_SCRAPERA is NOT NULL"
        count = all_count(sql_len)
 
    dic = {
        'draw': draw,
        'recordsTotal': count,
        'recordsFiltered': count,
        'data': data,
    }
 
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(dic), content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Have you tried referring to documentations for either. If yes, can you atleast share the code snippet of how you're trying to do it.

Comment: I have added snippets of my code

Comment: "_I would like the second button to create a new table in the database and save the same table to it_": You want users to be able to create new database tables at the click of a button, and populate those tables with a copy (or subset?) of the original data? That sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/671985), or just a bad idea. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: 'the same table to it as for Excel'. The new table is to contain a smaller dataset filtered on phrases. This data is uploaded to another service, I need a copy of it in the database.